# Notebook is initializing separate spark pool session in Azure synapse Foreach activity

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, foreach, azure-synapse

I have assigned a synapse spark notebook in foreach activity in Data pipeline .This will create separate spark session on each iteration and it is taking long time to run the activity .How to prevent synapse initializing separate spark pool session in each iteration .

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Sreekantg TN Can you please share the code you are using in your spark notebook?

Comment: Also Could you let me know why do you need stop the spark session in each iteration ?

Comment: I think you have disabled the sequential option in for each and that is the best approach to prevent synapse initializing separate spark pool session. it will execute all itterations at a time.
If you use spark.stop() and Use sequential it will stop and restart sequentially.